# When using angularjs to an existing single page website, do I need to use angular to maintain all the data?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

We have already a big single web page, say, a user information page with his/her favorite website links, the links can be displayed by group, or filtered.

The user information(e.g. username, email, address, photo, etc.) was rendering on the server side, and embedded to HTML. There are also some jQuery code to provide some interactions, e.g. the email of user won't fully displayed in the beginning, visitor has to click on it to show the full email.

Now we want to use angularjs to do the new features(e.g. manipulation the links). We don't use angularjs routes and still rendering the user information data somewhere inside the HTML, me and my colleague have the same idea about this.

But soon we have different opinions about how to embed the data:

1. My colleague prefer keeping current code untouched, that means we still use embedded user data all over the page, which may be maintained by jquery functions. And we will use both angularjs and jquery on the same page to operate on different data.
2. I prefer rendering the data as an angularjs constant of service, letting angularjs to render them. Also we will rewrite the jquery code to angular, in order to get better testing support and consistent way of rendering data. (The rewriting work is pretty easy)

But we can't convince each other. Although I prefer the second solution, but actually it's just a little better than the first one (in my opinion).

I'm looking for if there is any important factor I haven't realized, that we should choose one over the other, or either one is OK?

Comment: Why would you want to start using AngularJS in the first place? Is there any benefits of you starting to use that over just using the methods already implemented?

Comment: if you want to switch, why bypass all the data binding that angular offers and maintain 2 systems?

Comment: If you decided that angularJS is what you want to use from here on, the only decision to make is how much of the app you're going to rewrite, which is a business decision. You can surely use angularJS only for small parts of the app, but ideally you'd switch everything.